# How to load UIViews instead of UILabels for HMSegmentControl in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uisegmentedcontrol

I am working on iPhone app, where i need to add segments using multiple of titles. For the solution, i have added HMSegmentControl library in my app. It's working fine but the problem is that using UILabels it's working fine. Instead i need to load UIView's to display the screen when user will tap on any of the segment title button. I have tried but it's not working. Basically i want to load UIViews (which is connected in my XIB) for respective segments.

here is my code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

     screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    scrollTitle = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Alerts",@"Profile",@"Help",nil];
    tabBarArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Alerts",@"Profile",@"Help",nil];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    currentPage = 0;

    segmentedControll = [[HMSegmentedControl alloc] initWithSectionTitles:@[@"Alerts",@"Profile",@"Help"]];
    segmentedControll.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:227/255.0 green:230/255.0 blue:230/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    [segmentedControll setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 46, 320, 40)];
    [segmentedControll setSelectedSegmentIndex:1];
    containerView = [[HMSegmentedControlContainerView alloc] initWithHMSegmentedControl:segmentedControll andMinimumWIdth:107];

    containerView.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator=0;

    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [segmentedControll setIndexChangeBlock:^(NSInteger index) {
        [weakSelf.menuScrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(320 * index, 0, 320, 200) animated:YES];
    }];

    [self.view addSubview:containerView];
    totalNoOfSegment=3;
    currentPage=segmentedControll.selectedSegmentIndex;

    self.menuScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 87, 320, 373)];
    [self.menuScrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.7 green:0.7 blue:0.7 alpha:1]];
    [self.menuScrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
    [self.menuScrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [self.menuScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(960, 200)];
    [self.menuScrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 200) animated:NO];
    [self.menuScrollView setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addSubview:self.menuScrollView];

    /*UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 373)];
    [label1 setText:@"Alerts"];
    label1.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label1.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [self.menuScrollView addSubview:label1];*/

    [self.menuScrollView addSubview:viewAlerts];

    /*UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 373)];
    [label2 setText:@"Profile"];
    label2.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label2.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [self.menuScrollView addSubview:label2];*/

    [self.menuScrollView addSubview:viewProfile];

    /*UILabel *label3 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(640, 0, 320, 373)];
    [label3 setText:@"Help"];
    label3.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label3.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label3.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [self.menuScrollView addSubview:label3];*/

    [self.menuScrollView addSubview:viewHelp];


    self.panGestureLeft=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panTableView:)];
    self.panGestureLeft.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft ;
    [self.menuScrollView addGestureRecognizer:self.panGestureLeft];
    self.panGestureRight=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panTableView:)];
    self.panGestureRight.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight ;
    [self.menuScrollView addGestureRecognizer:self.panGestureRight];
}

-(void)panTableView:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)pan{
    if (pan.state==UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        int curr=currentPage;

        if (pan==self.panGestureLeft)
        {
            // user dragged towards the right
            curr=curr+1;
            if (curr!=3) {
                CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
                transition.duration = 0.35;
                transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
                transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
                transition.subtype =kCATransitionFromRight;
                transition.delegate = self;
                [self.menuScrollView.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
                segmentedControll.selectedSegmentIndex=curr;
                [self segmentedControlChangedValue:segmentedControll];
            }

        }
        else if (pan==self.panGestureRight)

        {
            // user dragged towards the left
            curr=curr-1;
            if (curr!=-1) {
                CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
                transition.duration = 0.35;
                transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
                transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
                transition.subtype =kCATransitionFromLeft;
                transition.delegate = self;
                [self.menuScrollView.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
                segmentedControll.selectedSegmentIndex=curr;
                [self segmentedControlChangedValue:segmentedControll];

            }
        }
    }
}

- (void)segmentedControlChangedValue:(HMSegmentedControl *)segmentedControl {
    NSLog(@"Selected index %i (via UIControlEventValueChanged)", segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex);
    currentPage=segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;
}
```

Here in my code, if i will add UIViews dynamically then it will work. But i need to add UIViews using XIB. Please help me to achieve my solution. Thanks

Comment: Is your  self.menuScrollView within your Xib or have you created it progrmmatically

Comment: Thanks @Geet, i have created self.menuScrollView programmatically.

Comment: Did you link your UIViews with the properties in your interface?

Comment: Then, It might be a bit difficult, what you can do is create the uIVIew in your XIB as a child to your main view, keep them hidden at first, then add them as a subview to the ScrollView by setting its contentOffset, and UnHide them, it might work

Comment: In my above code.. i am only loading UILabels. I have tried to add UIViews to the scroll view using XIB but it's not working.

Comment: Can you post your code for loading the subviews, make sure they are connected as IBOutlets

Comment: @Geeti have updated code in my question. i have added viewAlerts, viewProfile and viewHelp in my XIB. but bcos of same frame for all the UIViews i am getting only one view. please help me what i need to change here?

Comment: your Code's almost correct only thing you missed out is the frames of your UIVIEws

Comment: correct.. but how can i load different views according to the UIScroll View content size, it can be solve my problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57984/discussion-between-anand-gautam-and-geet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your Code's almost correct only thing you missed out is the frames of your UIViews Since Your are loading them in your ScrollView Which Is Made Programmatically, You need to set the frames of Your UIviews with the ScrollView, Considering the Content Offset of Your ScrollView

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfView; i++) {


    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
```

//Now set this Frame to your Views accordingly

}

Comment: Thanks alot.. no words for you @Geet.

Comment: I would recommend using CGGeometry functions, such as CGRectGetWidth(CGRect rect) for retrieving frame elements instead of accessing the width member directly. More details and other useful tips for ObjC   writing style: https://github.com/macoscope/objc-style-guide